# How obtain values by solving a formula

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

How  I can obtain the values of `x` and `y` from solving

```
100.*x.*3.2.*1e5-((exp(y.*x)-1).^1.5./(y.*x.*exp(y.*x)).^0.5) = 0
```

I know how to plot it by following:

```
ezplot('100.*x.*3.2.*1e5-((exp(y.*x)-1).^1.5./(y.*x.*exp(y.*x)).^0.5)', [xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h=ezplot('100.*x.*3.2.*1e5-((exp(y.*x)-1).^1.5./(y.*x.*exp(y.*x)).^0.5)', [xmin xmax ymin ymax])
XData = get(h, 'contourMatrix');
x=XData(1,:)'
y=XData(2,:)'
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation or documentation for this answer?

Answer (score 3):

So firstly you have 1 equation and 2 unknowns so your problem is under-specified and there will not be a unique solution.

Secondly you can find `x` in term of `y` with some basic algebra:

```
log(y./20)*(1+2.98e10*y) + x./10e-12 = 0  %// btw I imagine you actually want .* here but I'm sticking with your equation
```

∴

```
log(y./20)*(1+2.98e10*y) = - x./10e-12
```

∴

```
x = -10e-12(log(y./20)*(1+2.98e10*y))
```

so now if you want some numerical values try something like:

```
y = -10:0.1:10;
x = -10e-12(log(y./20)*(1+2.98e10*y))
```

and `plot(x,y)` should verify it for you

Comment: or Symbolic Toolbox for the lazy: `syms x y; solve(log(y/20)*(1 + 2.98e10*y) + x/10e-12 == 0)` :)

Comment: @Amro I've never used the symbolic toolbox. Maybe post as a separate answer? What would that give you? `x` i.t.o `y`?

Comment: same thing you did (x in terms of y), the answer is: `-(log(y/20)*(29800000000*y + 1))/100000000000`

Comment: Will give +1 for taking advantage of how simple the function is, but I still supplied an alternate solution for those who do not want to try algebra.

Comment: I just wrote a simple formula for an example. I have to solve 100.*x.*3.2.*1e5-((exp(y.*x)-1).^1.5./(y.*x.*exp(y.*x)).^0.5) = 0 Please help me to get values of x and y for this one?

Comment: @user3271929 ok so in that case what are you actually after? Do you want a numerical vector of `x` and `y` values? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Hi Dan :I want to get x and y that mutually works in this formula? I am confused how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the information generated by the plot, the simple solution is to assign the plot.

Here is how it is described in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html):

```
h = ezplot(...)
```

Then you can get the information by using:

```
d=get(h)
```

From here it should be something like:

```
d.XData
d.YData
```

Comment: Dennis: I want to get x and y that mutually works in this formula? I am confused how???

Comment: @user3271929 Have you tried adding `h =` before your line of code and looking at what `h` contains?

Comment: I just get one number

Comment: :( I do not know how to deal to find my answer?

Comment: @user3271929 Apparently I forgot the step to `get` the data. Please try it now.

Comment: I do not have yet x and y data:(

Comment: I got:  XData: [1x250 double]
             XDataMode: 'manual'
           XDataSource: ''
                 YData: [250x1 double]

Comment: Dennis: Can you please help me more

Comment: @user3271929 It seems like you already have 250 `x` values with their matching `y` values. Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: @ Dennis: I found how to deal with it :) see my answer-Thank you a lot